# Nginx proxy - proxy_set_header - custom header from site.conf (For Varnish Cache)

Tags: nginx, magento2, varnish, magento-2.3

Is it possible to send a **custom header** in your website and then forward it using `proxy_set_header` to Varnish?

#### Info

*I have moved folder locations a little bit - everything are included correctly and works.*

I have `/etc/nginx/conf.d/params/proxy.params/proxy_params` file with:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port-Nginx $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-DocumentRoot $document_root;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-Site 'Custom Site';   ### THIS IS THE HEADER I WANT TO BE DYNAMIC
fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
```

Then in my https server block in `sites-enabled/custom-site.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Custom-Location-Site' 'mysite1';
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name nginx-glo 192.168.1.105 localhost:443;

    location / {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        add_header 'Custom-Nginx-Server-Location-Root-Redirect' 'From /';   #### This header does not appear in varnishlog  (testing only)
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/params/proxy.params/proxy_params_destination.conf;
```

The relevant `proxy_params_destination.conf`:

```
server_tokens off;

proxy_redirect off;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/params/proxy.params/proxy_params;
# Try not to add headers using add_header, this will reset all headers from other locations
# that are redirected here.
# Also do not log to file here, log in locations above.

proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 356;
proxy_read_timeout 3600;
proxy_connect_timeout 60;
# Cannot use https:// for proxy calls - use http, outside connection is https
proxy_pass http://varnish-cache-magento2.3.5:6081;
#proxy_pass http://web-server-apache2-magento2.3.5:8080;
```

#### What I want to do:

- I have this header defined :
  `add_header 'Custom-Location-Site' 'mysite1'` in the website conf file.
- I want to receive the _value from that header for each website_and forward it here:
  `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-Site $how_can_I_get_Custom-Location-Site_here;` and then let Varnish cache receive this header in `vcl_recv{}`
- This forwarded header I will then handle in `vcl_recv{}`:
  using `req.http.X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-Site` as descibed in sample below.

#### Reason:

> Varnish cache setup for multiple Magento 2 sites.

- The sample from Varnish article below shows how I can do it with **paths**.  I can not use Paths, I have multiple Docker containers running different websites, and then forwards it to the *Varnish container*.  For example Container that runs `PHP 7.2`, other `PHP 7.3` websites, both running inside as `/var/www/html, https`

[Link to sample multiple backends](https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/content/tutorials/varnish/multiple_varnishes.html#:%7E:text=Multiple%20backends%20means%20serving%20from,to%20add%20a%20Java%20application.)

Relevant section in sample:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/java/") {
        set req.backend_hint = java;
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    }
}

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
Now let’s add a new backend:

backend java {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8000";
}
```

#### Varnishlog

As shown here: `varnishlog` already receives my custom headers in the Docker container. I just now need the value of the custom header to be dynamic.

```
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 192.168.1.103
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.1.103
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port-Nginx: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-DocumentRoot: /var/www/html
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-Site: Custom Site
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you need:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-Site $http_custom_location_site;
```

This makes the `X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-site` dynamic, based on the `server` block where you configured the `Custom-Location-Site` header.

If for example the value of `Custom-Location-Site` is `mysite1`, the `X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-site` value will be the following:

```
X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-site: mysite1
```

According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_, you can use `$http_` with any header. You just have to lowercase the value, and replace dashes with underscores.

Comment: This is indeed what I want to do, I want to be able to add_header from a location or site block then forward it to `proxy_params`.  I was not aware of using custom headers `$http_`, I always assumed those in the default proxy_params and other configs are built-in variables.  I will give this a try thanks!

Comment: I have just tried it, but now `X-Forwarded-Custom-Location-Site` does not reach the Varnish cache in `varnishlog`, its now gone.  As soon as I add a static value again in `proxy_params` (like I showed in example) then the header appears again.   I have tried `add_header 'Custom-Location-Site' 'site1-magento2.3.5';`   it in both the `server {}` root block, and inside the `location /` block as in my original example above.

Comment: If I disable the Varnish, `#proxy_pass http://varnish-cache-magento2.3.5:6081;` and set the location to the Apache web-server: `proxy_pass http://web-server-apache2-magento2.3.5:8080;`  I actually see both my headers in **Response**: `Custom-Nginx-Server-Location-Root-Redirect: From /` `Custom-Location-Site: site1-magento2.3.5
`.  This confirms the _location block is used_ but not sent with the request ?.  Is there a way to see **debug** headers info processed/sent before `proxy_pass` is used.

Comment: Missing something here, I have created an `error_log /var/location/root-debug.log debug` entry in `location / {}` block, I see the headers, but its logged **after** `http proxy header` entries `X-Forwarded`.  Are these custom $http only used in response? /confused now